# Only one label appears on my display

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, label

I'm new to coding and I have a little project to do for my class.
First I need to put two pictures on a display, I am using Jpanel labels to do it. However the way I'm doing only the picture "dog" appears. The dog and cat have to be on different panels. I don't understand why only one is showing up.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Cat extends JPanel
{
    //instance variables
    ImageIcon pic;
    JLabel label;

    public Cat()
    {
        //constructor
        pic = new ImageIcon("/Users/dell/Desktop/runKittyRun/cat.png");
       // setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        label = new JLabel(pic);
        add(label);
    }

}
```

======================================================

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Dog extends JPanel
{
    //instance variables
    ImageIcon pic2;
    JLabel label2;

    public Dog()
    {
        //constructor
        pic2 = new ImageIcon("/Users/dell/Desktop/runKittyRun/dog.png");        
        label2 = new JLabel(pic2);
       // add(label2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(label2);
    }

}
```

================================================

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Map {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map();
    }

    private static void map() {

                //Creates the frame where panels will be.
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Run Kitty Run!");
                frame.setSize(1000, 500);

                Cat player = new Cat();
                frame.add(player);

                Dog pc = new Dog();
                frame.add(pc);

                frame.setVisible(true);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, meaning that in it's default position (`CENTER`), it will only layout the last component added to that position.

Instead, you could use a `GridLayout`, for example

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Run Kitty Run!");
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

Cat player = new Cat();
frame.add(player);

Dog pc = new Dog();
frame.add(pc);
```

Have a look at [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details and examples of other layout managers

Comment: There really has to be many duplicate answers to this common question -- don't you think??

Comment: One duplicate found. Consider making your answer a community wiki.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That pretty much goes for any layout related question :P

Comment: True, but this is likely the most common of the common. It's verging on egregious.